# Koa - Best practice for yield error handling

Tags: koa, io.js

I'm getting my hands dirty in Koa.js and am looking for a best practice on returned error handling for generators, if there is one. Take the following:

```
var sql = require('./lib/sql');

app.use(function *(){
  var results = yield sql.query('select top 1 * from farm_animals;');
  this.body = results;
});
```

Now, a tradition approach I would be used to would be:

```
sql.query('select top 1 * from farm_animals;', function(err, data){
  if (!err) {
    // return data
  }
});
```

Now that I've converted `sql.query` into a `Promise`, I can't return `err` and `data`. So what should I return that could properly inform me of errors while returning the data? Perhaps I could adopt and stick to some standard:

```
{
  error: null,
  data: { id: 1, animal: 'cow' },
}
```

Before I do this however, I want to make sure there isn't some accepted best practice that I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use try/catch blocks.

See the following answer for more details:
[Error handling with promises in Koa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617117/error-handling-with-promises-in-koa/29618878#29618878)